# Kernel panic using deferred_io on kmalloced buffer

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, framebuffer, panic

I'm writing a framebuffer for an SPI LCD display on ARM. Before I complete that, I've written a memory only driver and trialled it under Ubuntu (Intel, Virtualbox). The driver works fine - I've allocated a block of memory using kmalloc, page aligned it (it's page aligned anyway actually), and used the framebuffer system to create a /dev/fb1. I have my own mmap function if that's relevant (deferred_io ignores it and uses its own by the look of it).

I have set:

```
info->screen_base = (u8 __iomem *)kmemptr;
info->fix.smem_len = kmem_size;
```

When I open /dev/fb1 with a test program and mmap it, it works correctly. I can see what is happening x11vnc to "share" the fb1 out:

```
x11vnc -rawfb map:/dev/fb1@320x240x16
```

And view with a vnc viewer:

```
gvncviewer strontium:0
```

I've made sure I've no overflows by writing to the entire mmapped buffer and that seems to be fine.

The problem arises when I add in deferred_io. As a test of it, I have a delay of 1 second and the called deferred_io function does nothing except a pr_devel() print. I followed the [docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/deferred_io.txt).

Now, the test program opens /dev/fb1 fine, mmap returns ok but as soon as I write to that pointer, I get a kernel panic. The following dump is from the ARM machine actually but it panics on the Ubuntu VM as well:

```
root@duovero:~/testdrv# ./fbtest1 /dev/fb1
Device opened: /dev/fb3
Screen is: 320 x 240, 16 bpp
Screen size = 153600 bytes
mmap on device succeeded

Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address bf81e020
pgd = edbec000
[bf81e020] *pgd=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] SMP ARM
Modules linked in: hhlcd28a(O) sysimgblt sysfillrect syscopyarea fb_sys_fops bnep ipv6 mwifiex_sdio mwifiex btmrvl_sdio firmware_class btmrvl cfg80211 bluetooth rfkill
CPU: 0    Tainted: G           O  (3.6.0-hh04 #1)
PC is at fb_deferred_io_fault+0x34/0xb0
LR is at fb_deferred_io_fault+0x2c/0xb0
pc : [<c0271b7c>]    lr : [<c0271b74>]    psr: a0000113
sp : edbdfdb8  ip : 00000000  fp : edbeedb8
r10: edbeedb8  r9 : 00000029  r8 : edbeedb8
r7 : 00000029  r6 : bf81e020  r5 : eda99128  r4 : edbdfdd8
r3 : c081e000  r2 : f0000000  r1 : 00001000  r0 : bf81e020
Flags: NzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Control: 10c5387d  Table: adbec04a  DAC: 00000015
Process fbtest1 (pid: 485, stack limit = 0xedbde2f8)
Stack: (0xedbdfdb8 to 0xedbe0000)
[snipped out hexdump]
[<c0271b7c>] (fb_deferred_io_fault+0x34/0xb0) from [<c00db0c4>] (__do_fault+0xbc/0x470)
[<c00db0c4>] (__do_fault+0xbc/0x470) from [<c00dde0c>] (handle_pte_fault+0x2c4/0x790)
[<c00dde0c>] (handle_pte_fault+0x2c4/0x790) from [<c00de398>] (handle_mm_fault+0xc0/0xd4)
[<c00de398>] (handle_mm_fault+0xc0/0xd4) from [<c049a038>] (do_page_fault+0x140/0x37c)
[<c049a038>] (do_page_fault+0x140/0x37c) from [<c0008348>] (do_DataAbort+0x34/0x98)
[<c0008348>] (do_DataAbort+0x34/0x98) from [<c0498af4>] (__dabt_usr+0x34/0x40)
Exception stack(0xedbdffb0 to 0xedbdfff8)
ffa0:                                     00000280 0000ffff b6f5c900 00000000
ffc0: 00000003 00000000 00025800 b6f5c900 bea6dc1c 00011048 00000032 b6f5b000
ffe0: 00006450 bea6db70 00000000 000085d6 40000030 ffffffff
Code: 28bd8070 ebffff37 e2506000 0a00001b (e5963000)
---[ end trace 7e5ca57bebd433f5 ]---
Segmentation fault
root@duovero:~/testdrv#
```

I'm totally stumped - other drivers look more or less the same as mine but I assume they work. Most use vmalloc actually - is there a difference between kmalloc and vmalloc for this purpose?

Comment: Oh crumbs! I think I see something. deferred_io appears to treat vmalloc differently - does the call to is_vmalloc_addr() return not true for a kmalloced address? If so, the darn thing uses info->fix.smem_start instead of screen base. And I don't set that! It uses pfn_to_page which I suppose is a physical address. This should be documented!

Comment: That's the issue - I'm sure of it. The act of typing the question solved it for me! It appears deferred io treats kmalloc and vmalloc differently. I'll write a solution as someone else will hit this and I'll try and update the kernel docs.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed the fix so I'll answer my own question:

deferred_io changes the info mmap to its own that sets up fault handlers for writes to the video memory pages. In the fault handler it

- checks bounds against info->fix.smem_len, so you must set that
- gets the page that was written to.

For the latter case, it treats vmalloc differently from kmalloc (by checking info->screen_base to see if it's vmalloced). If you have vmalloced, it uses screen_base as the virtual address. If you have not used vmalloc, it assumes that the address of interest is the *physical* address in info->fix.smem_start.

So, to use deferred_io correctly

- set screen_base (char __iomem *) and point that to the virtual address.
- set info->fix.smem_len to the video buffer size
- if you are not using vmalloc, you *must* set info->fix.smem_start to the video buffer's physical address by using virt_to_phys(vid_buffer);

Confirmed on Ubuntu as fixing the issue.

Comment: And breaks on ARM on the munmap. Life is hard I guess.

Answer (score -1):

Really interesting, I'm currently implementing SPI-based display FB driver too (Sharp Memory LCD display and my VFDHack32 host driver). I also facing similar problem where it crashes at deferred_io. Can you share you source code ? mine is at [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/TiNredmc/linux/blob/nano-5.2-flash/drivers/video/fbdev/sharp_memlcd.c). P.S. that Memory LCD display is monochrome so I just pretend to be color display and just check whether the pixel byte is empty (dot off) or not empty (dot on).

Comment: if your opinions doesn't include a solution of given problem, you had better write it as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your guide, btw I'm new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: I'll be honest and say that after seven years I haven't very much of a clue, even looking at my own code! Bear in mind that Linux kernel may have changed in that time too. My code's comments say I decided to use vzalloc ("stupid bug in deferred io") for the video buffer and kmalloc for the spi buffer. God knows why I did that. I also needed to manually page align the return from kmalloc. From my notes, I was referencing work done by Noralf Trønnes (https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki) and also https://github.com/rm-hull/fbtft. These repos may give you more info than my code could...