# Debugging a kernel panic when using Cairo graphics with an 8 bit per pixel frame buffer

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, cairo, framebuffer

I successfully got a 1 bit per pixel frame buffer working with Cairo Graphics and I’m running into issues converting the frame buffer to 8 bits per pixel.

In the frame buffer I increased the appropriate values by a factor of 8 and for a 128x64 display I get 8192 bytes of memory allocated in the driver.

Testing from the command line with `cat /dev/urandom > /dev/fb0` works as expected.

I then use Cairo to draw a diagonal line just to test the boundaries and that’s when I start seeing issues, so I assume it's an issue with deferred IO in the frame buffer.  Seems similar to [Kernel panic using deferred_io on kmalloced buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285151/kernel-panic-using-deferred-io-on-kmalloced-buffer)

I've hit a road block and need help moving forward.

Drawing a line from 0x,0y to 63x,0y has no problems.

```
cairo_move_to(cr,0,0);
cairo_line_to(cr,63,1);
cairo_stroke(cr);
```

Drawing from 0,0 to 64,0 I start seeing the following until 0,0 to 128,31:

```
[  579.978373] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  579.992339] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1920 at kernel/ptrace.c:190 SyS_ptrace+0x388/0x5c8()
[  580.044483] Modules linked in: musb_dsps musb_hdrc udc_core musb_am335x
[  580.176439] CPU: 0 PID: 1920 Comm: strace Not tainted 4.1.18-rt17 #121
[  580.183027] Hardware name: Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)
[  580.189150] Backtrace:
[  580.191692] [<c0013208>] (dump_backtrace) from [<c0013428>] (show_stack+0x18/0x1c)
[  580.199324]  r7:c06fc844 r6:000000be r5:00000009 r4:00000000
[  580.205072] [<c0013410>] (show_stack) from [<c059c968>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
[  580.212365] [<c059c948>] (dump_stack) from [<c003a32c>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x80/0xb8)
[  580.220503] [<c003a2ac>] (warn_slowpath_common) from [<c003a408>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x24/0x2c)
[  580.229349]  r8:00000000 r7:00000000 r6:00000018 r5:cc36668c r4:cc366680
[  580.236184] [<c003a3e4>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<c0042c84>] (SyS_ptrace+0x388/0x5c8)
[  580.244348] [<c00428fc>] (SyS_ptrace) from [<c000f800>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x3c)
[  580.252062]  r9:cd6c4000 r8:c000f9a4 r7:0000001a r6:00000783 r5:b6f8b4d0 r4:00000017
[  580.259896] ---[ end trace 0000000000000002 ]---
```

Drawing at 128,32 and above causes a kernel panic:

```
[  984.692851] flags: 0x14(referenced|dirty)
[  984.697350] page dumped because: non-NULL mapping
[  984.703013] Modules linked in: musb_dsps musb_hdrc udc_core musb_am335x
[  984.709706] CPU: 0 PID: 2295 Comm: test Tainted: G        W       4.1.18-rt17 #121
[  984.717864] Hardware name: Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)
[  984.725323] Backtrace:
[  984.727874] [<c0013208>] (dump_backtrace) from [<c0013428>] (show_stack+0x18/0x1c)
[  984.736361]  r7:00000000 r6:c07055d0 r5:cff87cb4 r4:c0880c80
[  984.742767] [<c0013410>] (show_stack) from [<c059c968>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
[  984.750440] [<c059c948>] (dump_stack) from [<c00e0620>] (bad_page+0xc8/0x12c)
[  984.761358] [<c00e0558>] (bad_page) from [<c00e08b8>] (free_pages_prepare+0x234/0x2f0)
[  984.770049]  r9:cc215dc8 r8:cff87cb4 r7:00000001 r6:00000001 r5:cff87cb4 r4:cfdad000
[  984.777961] [<c00e0684>] (free_pages_prepare) from [<c00e2944>] (free_hot_cold_page+0x34/0x298)
[  984.787421]  r10:c08616f0 r9:cc215dc8 r8:00080000 r7:00000000 r6:00000014 r5:cff87cb4
[  984.795881]  r4:cfdad000
[  984.798476] [<c00e2910>] (free_hot_cold_page) from [<c00e2bf4>] (free_hot_cold_page_list+0x4c/0xec)
[  984.809020]  r10:c08616f0 r9:cc215dc8 r8:cc214000 r7:cc215db4 r6:00000000 r5:cff87cb4
[  984.817006]  r4:cff87cb4
[  984.819598] [<c00e2ba8>] (free_hot_cold_page_list) from [<c00ea080>] (release_pages+0x24c/0x264)
[  984.829523]  r10:cc215dc8 r9:00000002 r8:cc36d004 r7:00000002 r6:00000000 r5:00000002
[  984.837500]  r4:cff87cb4 r3:00000000
[  984.847293] [<c00e9e34>] (release_pages) from [<c0116f74>] (free_pages_and_swap_cache+0xa0/0xa4)
[  984.858132]  r10:b6f50000 r9:cc215eb8 r8:cc36d000 r7:00000002 r6:cc36d004 r5:cff87cb4
[  984.866577]  r4:00000002
[  984.869406] [<c0116ed4>] (free_pages_and_swap_cache) from [<c0105c40>] (unmap_single_vma+0x3f8/0x59c)
[  984.880475]  r9:cc215eb8 r8:b6f50000 r7:cff87cb4 r6:b6f4f000 r5:8d30534f r4:00000000
[  984.888944] [<c0105848>] (unmap_single_vma) from [<c0106bc0>] (unmap_vmas+0x5c/0x70)
[  984.898548]  r10:b6f4e000 r9:cc4ab318 r8:00000000 r7:b6f4e000 r6:cc215eb8 r5:b6f50000
[  984.906901]  r4:cd6f2370
[  984.909555] [<c0106b64>] (unmap_vmas) from [<c0109f0c>] (unmap_region+0xb4/0x1ac)
[  984.919229]  r8:cd6f2370 r7:cc215ee0 r6:b6f50000 r5:cd4af8f0 r4:cc51b700
[  984.926694] [<c0109e58>] (unmap_region) from [<c010bddc>] (do_munmap+0x28c/0x3fc)
[  984.935467]  r10:cd6f2370 r9:cc4ab318 r8:cc51b704 r7:b6f4e000 r6:b6f50000 r5:cd6f2370
[  984.945040]  r4:cc51b700
[  984.948196] [<c010bb50>] (do_munmap) from [<c010bf90>] (vm_munmap+0x44/0x58)
[  984.956689]  r10:00000100 r9:cc214000 r8:c000f9a4 r7:00002000 r6:b6f4e000 r5:cc51b700
[  984.965245]  r4:cc51b748
[  984.967906] [<c010bf4c>] (vm_munmap) from [<c010cf2c>] (SyS_munmap+0x24/0x28)
[  984.976574]  r7:0000005b r6:00029a30 r5:00002000 r4:b6f4e000
[  984.982811] [<c010cf08>] (SyS_munmap) from [<c000f974>] (__sys_trace_return+0x0/0x2c)
[  984.990844]  r5:00000001 r4:00029858
[  984.998016] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[  985.602383] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address a2763fc4
[  985.609738] pgd = c0004000
[  985.613681] [a2763fc4] *pgd=00000000
[  985.617326] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT ARM
[  985.617347] Modules linked in: musb_dsps musb_hdrc udc_core musb_am335x
[  985.617363] CPU: 0 PID: 1766 Comm: kworker/0:0 Tainted: G    B   W       4.1.18-rt17 #121
[  985.617367] Hardware name: Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)
[  985.617397] Workqueue: events fb_deferred_io_work
[  985.617403] task: cc364000 ti: cc44a000 task.ti: cc44a000
[  985.617420] PC is at __wake_up_bit+0x10/0x48
[  985.617436] LR is at unlock_page+0x38/0x3c
[  985.617445] pc : [<c0065b9c>]    lr : [<c00dba2c>]    psr: a00f0013
[  985.617445] sp : cc44be98  ip : cc44beb8  fp : cc44beb4
[  985.617449] r10: cfd86500  r9 : 0cfd8650  r8 : 00000000
[  985.617455] r7 : cd24dc00  r6 : cd2b9150  r5 : cd2b9154  r4 : cc215db4
[  985.617460] r3 : 289d8fec  r2 : 00000000  r1 : cc215db4  r0 : a2763fb0
[  985.617469] Flags: NzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment kernel
[  985.617475] Control: 10c5387d  Table: 8d4f0019  DAC: 00000015
[  985.617480] Process kworker/0:0 (pid: 1766, stack limit = 0xcc44a210)
[  985.617486] Stack: (0xcc44be98 to 0xcc44c000)
[  985.617495] be80:                                                       c07f0000 cff87cb4
[  985.617506] bea0: 00000000 cc44bea0 cc44becc cc44beb8 c00dba2c c0065b98 cc215db4 cd2b9154
[  985.617518] bec0: cc44beec cc44bed0 c0305528 c00dba00 cd24de28 cd496380 c0860f5c c07ff8b8
[  985.617529] bee0: cc44bf2c cc44bef0 c004fdac c03054f0 cc44a000 cc364000 cc44bf14 00000000
[  985.617540] bf00: c0050a34 c07ff8b8 cd496398 c07ff8dc 00000008 c0860c6d c07ff8b8 cd496380
[  985.617550] bf20: cc44bf64 cc44bf30 c0050120 c004fc9c 00000000 c07ff8dc 00000000 00000000
[  985.617561] bf40: cd713fc0 cd496380 c00500e8 00000000 00000000 00000000 cc44bfac cc44bf68
[  985.617572] bf60: c0054cd4 c00500f4 00000000 00000000 00000000 cd496380 00000000 cc44bf7c
[  985.617582] bf80: cc44bf7c 00000000 cc44bf88 cc44bf88 cd713fc0 c0054c08 00000000 00000000
[  985.617593] bfa0: 00000000 cc44bfb0 c000f8a8 c0054c14 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  985.617603] bfc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  985.617613] bfe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  985.617617] Backtrace:
[  985.617634] [<c0065b8c>] (__wake_up_bit) from [<c00dba2c>] (unlock_page+0x38/0x3c)
[  985.617648] [<c00db9f4>] (unlock_page) from [<c0305528>] (fb_deferred_io_work+0x44/0xe4)
[  985.617656]  r5:cd2b9154 r4:cc215db4
[  985.617680] [<c03054e4>] (fb_deferred_io_work) from [<c004fdac>] (process_one_work+0x11c/0x458)
[  985.617692]  r7:c07ff8b8 r6:c0860f5c r5:cd496380 r4:cd24de28
[  985.617707] [<c004fc90>] (process_one_work) from [<c0050120>] (worker_thread+0x38/0x52c)
[  985.617723]  r10:cd496380 r9:c07ff8b8 r8:c0860c6d r7:00000008 r6:c07ff8dc r5:cd496398
[  985.617727]  r4:c07ff8b8
[  985.617744] [<c00500e8>] (worker_thread) from [<c0054cd4>] (kthread+0xcc/0xe4)
[  985.617760]  r10:00000000 r9:00000000 r8:00000000 r7:c00500e8 r6:cd496380 r5:cd713fc0
[  985.617764]  r4:00000000
[  985.617783] [<c0054c08>] (kthread) from [<c000f8a8>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x2c)
[  985.617795]  r7:00000000 r6:00000000 r5:c0054c08 r4:cd713fc0
[  985.617806] Code: e1a0c00d e92dd800 e24cb004 e24dd010 (e590e014)
[  985.927655] ---[ end trace 0000000000000006 ]---
```

Here are the relative parts of the frame buffer driver:

```
static const struct fb_var_screeninfo oledfb_var = {
  .bits_per_pixel = 8,
  .grayscale = 1,
};

vmem_size = par->width * par->height * oledfb_var.bits_per_pixel / 8;
  vmem = (void *)__get_free_pages(GFP_KERNEL | __GFP_ZERO,
          get_order(vmem_size));

info->fix.line_length = par->width * oledfb_var.bits_per_pixel / 8;
info->var.red.length = oledfb_var.bits_per_pixel;
  info->var.red.offset = 0;
  info->var.red.msb_right = 1;
  info->var.green.length = oledfb_var.bits_per_pixel;
  info->var.green.offset = 0;
  info->var.green.msb_right = 1;
  info->var.blue.length = oledfb_var.bits_per_pixel;
  info->var.blue.offset = 0;
  info->var.blue.msb_right = 1;
  info->var.transp.length = oledfb_var.bits_per_pixel;
  info->var.transp.offset = 0;
  info->var.transp.msb_right = 1;

  info->screen_base = (u8 __force __iomem *)vmem;
  info->fix.smem_start = __pa(vmem);
  info->fix.smem_len = vmem_size;
```

And here is how I’m initializing my memory map and surface in cairo:

```
// Figure out the size of the screen in bytes
    device->fb_screensize = device->fb_vinfo.xres * device->fb_vinfo.yres
                            * device->fb_vinfo.bits_per_pixel / 8;
printf("  Size (bytes): %d\n", (int)device->fb_screensize);

printf("Mapping memory\n");
    // Map the device to memory
    device->fb_data = (char *)mmap(0, device->fb_screensize,
                                   PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,
                                   device->fb_fd, 0);
    if ((int)device->fb_data == -1) {
        perror("Error: failed to map framebuffer device to memory");
        exit(4);
    }

    // Get fixed screen information
    if (ioctl(device->fb_fd, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &device->fb_finfo) == -1) {
        perror("Error reading fixed information");
        exit(2);
    }

printf("  Stride_for_width: %d\n", cairo_format_stride_for_width(CAIRO_FORMAT_A8, device->fb_vinfo.xres));

    surface = cairo_image_surface_create_for_data((unsigned char *)device->fb_data,
                  CAIRO_FORMAT_A8,
                  device->fb_vinfo.xres,
                  device->fb_vinfo.yres,
                  cairo_format_stride_for_width(CAIRO_FORMAT_A8, device->fb_vinfo.xres));
    cairo_surface_set_user_data(surface, NULL, device, &cairo_linuxfb_surface_destroy);
```

Comment: Judging by your ptrace warning (which looks like the process state is messed up) and by the kernel panic, I would be inclined to investigate some buffer overflow. You might be allocating a too small buffer. One thing that I noticed is that you are setting red, green and blue depths, but you are not allocating a buffer nor expecting an RGB format. Perhaps you can output the full driver and I can take a better look?

Comment: @EzequielGarcia I am setting the red, green, and blue depths according to the API documentation at [link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/api.txt).  Offsets are 0 and lengths are equal to the bits per pixel (8). For a 128x64 display with 8bpp I am allocating 8192 bytes which makes sense.

"For grayscale formats, applications set the grayscale field to one. The red, blue, green and transp fields must be set to 0 by applications and ignored by drivers. **Drivers must fill the red, blue and green offsets to 0 and lengths to the bits_per_pixel value.**"

Comment: Hm, maybe. But those stack traces still look like some memory is crap due to overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
vmem = (void *)__get_free_pages(GFP_KERNEL | __GFP_ZERO, get_order(vmem_size));
...
__free_pages(__va(info->fix.smem_start), get_order(info->fix.smem_len));
```

to

```
vmem = kzalloc(vmem_size, GFP_KERNEL);
...
kfree(info->screen_base);
```

and that seems to have fixed the problem.  I based my driver off of https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/video/fbdev/ssd1307fb.c since the hardware is similar.  I don't know enough to understand why one way works over the other but the __ in front of the function call raised a red flag.

Comment: It honestly sounds like you are just covering the bug by switching to kmalloc. You might be stepping into memory, but since it's now allocated by kmalloc, maybe you get luckier and don't crash.

Comment: @EzequielGarcia Is it possible that get_free_pages is allocating nonconsecutive bytes vs kzalloc?  I noticed that other drivers use the following in the their deferred_io functions:

`/* walk the written page list and swizzle the data */
 list_for_each_entry(cur, &fbdefio->pagelist, lru) {
  cksum = metronomefb_dpy_update_page(par,
     (cur->index << PAGE_SHIFT));
  par->metromem_img_csum -= par->csum_table[cur->index];
  par->csum_table[cur->index] = cksum;
  par->metromem_img_csum += cksum;`

Comment: Hm, no. get_free_pages should give you a contiguous area.